# How to combine two or more pdf scroll bars or single scroll bar for more than one pdf in angular/PDFJS

Tags: angular, pdf, scrollbar, pdf.js

Problem : I am using pdf viewer in angular and trying to display pdf file one after another but facing scroll bar issue that is two pdf are getting overlapped,(please find attached file) and this problem is because of scroll bar that each pdf is getting its own scroll bar and i want only one scroll bar for all the pdf files

Code :
file 1 : document-viewer.component.ts

```
<div *ngIf="fileList.length > 0">
  <div *ngFor="let file of fileList">
    <pdf-viewer [src]="file.fileUrl" [show-all]="true" style="width: 100%; height: 80vh">
    </pdf-viewer>
  </div>
</div>
```

here `<pdf-viewer>` is a component where am using pdf viewer

file 2 : pdf-viewer.component.ts

```
 import {
    Component,
    Input,
    Output,
    ElementRef,
    EventEmitter,
    OnChanges,
    SimpleChanges,
    OnInit,
    OnDestroy,
    ViewChild,
    AfterViewChecked,
    NgZone
  } from '@angular/core';
  import { from, fromEvent, Subject } from 'rxjs';
  import { debounceTime, filter, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
  import * as PDFJS from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf';
  import * as PDFJSViewer from 'pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer';
  
  import { createEventBus } from './utils/event-bus-utils';
  import { assign, isSSR } from './utils/helpers';
  
  import type {
    PDFSource,
    PDFPageProxy,
    PDFProgressData,
    PDFDocumentProxy,
    PDFDocumentLoadingTask,
    PDFViewerOptions
  } from './typings';
  import { PDFSinglePageViewer } from 'pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer';
  
  if (!isSSR()) {
    assign(PDFJS, 'verbosity', PDFJS.VerbosityLevel.INFOS);
  }
  
  export enum RenderTextMode {
    DISABLED,
    ENABLED,
    ENHANCED
  }
  
  @Component({
    selector: 'pdf-viewer',
    template: `
      <div #pdfViewerContainer class="ng2-pdf-viewer-container">
        <div class="pdfViewer"></div>
      </div>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./pdf-viewer.component.scss']
  })
  export class PdfViewerComponent
    implements OnChanges, OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewChecked {
    static CSS_UNITS = 96.0 / 72.0;
    static BORDER_WIDTH = 9;
  
    @ViewChild('pdfViewerContainer') pdfViewerContainer;
  
    public eventBus: PDFJSViewer.EventBus;
    public pdfLinkService: PDFJSViewer.PDFLinkService;
    public pdfFindController: PDFJSViewer.PDFFindController;
    public pdfViewer: PDFJSViewer.PDFViewer | PDFSinglePageViewer;
  
    private isVisible = false;
  
    private _cMapsUrl =
      typeof PDFJS !== 'undefined'
        ? `https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@${(PDFJS as any).version}/cmaps/`
        : null;
    private _imageResourcesPath =
      typeof PDFJS !== 'undefined'
        ? `https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@${(PDFJS as any).version}/web/images/`
        : null;
    private _renderText = true;
    private _renderTextMode: RenderTextMode = RenderTextMode.ENABLED;
    private _stickToPage = false;
    private _originalSize = true;
    private _pdf: PDFDocumentProxy;
    private _page = 1;
    private _zoom = 1;
    private _zoomScale: 'page-height' | 'page-fit' | 'page-width' = 'page-width';
    private _rotation = 0;
    private _showAll = true;
    private _canAutoResize = true;
    private _fitToPage = false;
    private _externalLinkTarget = 'blank';
    private _showBorders = false;
    private lastLoaded: string | Uint8Array | PDFSource;
    private _latestScrolledPage: number;
  
    private resizeTimeout: number | null = null;
    private pageScrollTimeout: number | null = null;
    private isInitialized = false;
    private loadingTask: PDFDocumentLoadingTask;
    private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();
  
    @Output('after-load-complete') afterLoadComplete = new EventEmitter<PDFDocumentProxy>();
    @Output('page-rendered') pageRendered = new EventEmitter<CustomEvent>();
    @Output('pages-initialized') pageInitialized = new EventEmitter<CustomEvent>();
    @Output('text-layer-rendered') textLayerRendered = new EventEmitter<CustomEvent>();
    @Output('error') onError = new EventEmitter<any>();
    @Output('on-progress') onProgress = new EventEmitter<PDFProgressData>();
    @Output() pageChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>(true);
    @Input() src: string | Uint8Array | PDFSource;
  
    @Input('c-maps-url')
    set cMapsUrl(cMapsUrl: string) {
      this._cMapsUrl = cMapsUrl;
    }
  
    @Input('page')
    set page(_page) {
      _page = parseInt(_page, 10) || 1;
      const originalPage = _page;
  
      if (this._pdf) {
        _page = this.getValidPageNumber(_page);
      }
  
      this._page = _page;
      if (originalPage !== _page) {
        this.pageChange.emit(_page);
      }
    }
  
    @Input('render-text')
    set renderText(renderText: boolean) {
      this._renderText = renderText;
    }
  
    @Input('render-text-mode')
    set renderTextMode(renderTextMode: RenderTextMode) {
      this._renderTextMode = renderTextMode;
    }
  
    @Input('original-size')
    set originalSize(originalSize: boolean) {
      this._originalSize = originalSize;
    }
  
    @Input('show-all')
    set showAll(value: boolean) {
      this._showAll = value;
    }
  
    @Input('stick-to-page')
    set stickToPage(value: boolean) {
      this._stickToPage = value;
    }
  
    @Input('zoom')
    set zoom(value: number) {
      if (value <= 0) {
        return;
      }
  
      this._zoom = value;
    }
  
    get zoom() {
      return this._zoom;
    }
  
    @Input('zoom-scale')
    set zoomScale(value: 'page-height' | 'page-fit' | 'page-width') {
      this._zoomScale = value;
    }
  
    get zoomScale() {
      return this._zoomScale;
    }
  
    @Input('rotation')
    set rotation(value: number) {
      if (!(typeof value === 'number' && value % 90 === 0)) {
        console.warn('Invalid pages rotation angle.');
        return;
      }
  
      this._rotation = value;
    }
  
    @Input('external-link-target')
    set externalLinkTarget(value: string) {
      this._externalLinkTarget = value;
    }
  
    @Input('autoresize')
    set autoresize(value: boolean) {
      this._canAutoResize = Boolean(value);
    }
  
    @Input('fit-to-page')
    set fitToPage(value: boolean) {
      this._fitToPage = Boolean(value);
    }
  
    @Input('show-borders')
    set showBorders(value: boolean) {
      this._showBorders = Boolean(value);
    }
  
    static getLinkTarget(type: string) {

  
      return null;
    }
  
    constructor(private element: ElementRef<HTMLElement>, private ngZone: NgZone) {
      if (isSSR()) {
        return;
      }
  
      let pdfWorkerSrc: string;
  
      if (
        window.hasOwnProperty('pdfWorkerSrc') &&
        typeof (window as any).pdfWorkerSrc === 'string' &&
        (window as any).pdfWorkerSrc
      ) {
        pdfWorkerSrc = (window as any).pdfWorkerSrc;
      } else {
        pdfWorkerSrc = `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@${(PDFJS as any).version
          }/legacy/build/pdf.worker.min.js`;
      }
  
      assign(PDFJS.GlobalWorkerOptions, 'workerSrc', pdfWorkerSrc);
    }
  
    ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
      if (this.isInitialized) {
        return;
      }
  
      const offset = this.pdfViewerContainer.nativeElement.offsetParent;
  
      if (this.isVisible === true && offset == null) {
        this.isVisible = false;
        return;
      }
  
      if (this.isVisible === false && offset != null) {
        this.isVisible = true;
  
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.initialize();
          this.ngOnChanges({ src: this.src } as any);
        });
      }
    }
  
    ngOnInit() {
      this.initialize();
      this.setupResizeListener();
    }
  
    ngOnDestroy() {
      this.clear();
      this.destroy$.next();
      this.loadingTask = null;
    }
  
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
      if (isSSR() || !this.isVisible) {
        return;
      }
  
      if ('src' in changes) {
        this.loadPDF();
      } else if (this._pdf) {
        if ('renderText' in changes) {
          this.pdfViewer.textLayerMode = this._renderText
            ? this._renderTextMode
            : RenderTextMode.DISABLED;
          this.resetPdfDocument();
        } else if ('showAll' in changes) {
          this.setupViewer();
          this.resetPdfDocument();
        }
        if ('page' in changes) {
          const { page } = changes;
          if (page.currentValue === this._latestScrolledPage) {
            return;
          }
  
         
          this.pdfViewer.scrollPageIntoView({ pageNumber: this._page });
        }
  
        this.update();
      }
    }
  
    public updateSize() {
      from(
        this._pdf.getPage(
          this.pdfViewer.currentPageNumber
        ) as unknown as Promise<PDFPageProxy>
      )
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
        .subscribe({
          next: (page: PDFPageProxy) => {
            const rotation = this._rotation || page.rotate;
            const viewportWidth =
              (page as any).getViewport({
                scale: this._zoom,
                rotation
              }).width * PdfViewerComponent.CSS_UNITS;
            let scale = this._zoom;
            let stickToPage = true;
  
       
            if (
              !this._originalSize ||
              (this._fitToPage &&
                viewportWidth > this.pdfViewerContainer.nativeElement.clientWidth)
            ) {
              const viewPort = (page as any).getViewport({ scale: 1, rotation });
              scale = this.getScale(viewPort.width, viewPort.height);
              stickToPage = !this._stickToPage;
            }
  
            this.pdfViewer._setScale(scale, stickToPage);
          }
        });
    }
  
    public clear() {
      if (this.loadingTask && !this.loadingTask.destroyed) {
        this.loadingTask.destroy();
      }
  
      if (this._pdf) {
        this._latestScrolledPage = 0;
        this._pdf.destroy();
        this._pdf = null;
        this.pdfViewer.setDocument(null);
        this.pdfLinkService.setDocument(null, null);
        this.pdfFindController.setDocument(null);
      }
    }
  
    private getPDFLinkServiceConfig() {
      const linkTarget = PdfViewerComponent.getLinkTarget(this._externalLinkTarget);
  
      if (linkTarget) {
        return { externalLinkTarget: linkTarget };
      }
  
      return {};
    }
  
    private initEventBus() {
      this.eventBus = createEventBus(PDFJSViewer, this.destroy$);
  
      fromEvent<CustomEvent>(this.eventBus, 'pagerendered')
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
        .subscribe((event) => {
          this.pageRendered.emit(event);
        });
  
      fromEvent<CustomEvent>(this.eventBus, 'pagesinit')
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
        .subscribe((event) => {
          this.pageInitialized.emit(event);
        });
  
      fromEvent(this.eventBus, 'pagechanging')
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
        .subscribe(({ pageNumber }) => {
          if (this.pageScrollTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(this.pageScrollTimeout);
          }
  
          this.pageScrollTimeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
            this._latestScrolledPage = pageNumber;
            this.pageChange.emit(pageNumber);
          }, 100);
        });
  
      fromEvent<CustomEvent>(this.eventBus, 'textlayerrendered')
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
        .subscribe((event) => {
          this.textLayerRendered.emit(event);
        });
    }
  
    private initPDFServices() {
      this.pdfLinkService = new PDFJSViewer.PDFLinkService({
        eventBus: this.eventBus,
        ...this.getPDFLinkServiceConfig()
      });
      this.pdfFindController = new PDFJSViewer.PDFFindController({
        eventBus: this.eventBus,
        linkService: this.pdfLinkService,
      });
    }
  
    private getPDFOptions(): PDFViewerOptions {
      return {
        eventBus: this.eventBus,
        container: this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('div'),
        removePageBorders: !this._showBorders,
        linkService: this.pdfLinkService,
        textLayerMode: this._renderText
          ? this._renderTextMode
          : RenderTextMode.DISABLED,
        findController: this.pdfFindController,
        renderer: 'canvas',
        l10n: undefined,
        imageResourcesPath: this._imageResourcesPath,
      };
    }
  
    private setupViewer() {
      assign(PDFJS, 'disableTextLayer', !this._renderText);
  
      this.initPDFServices();
  
      if (this._showAll) {
        this.pdfViewer = new PDFJSViewer.PDFViewer(this.getPDFOptions());
      } else {
        this.pdfViewer = new PDFJSViewer.PDFSinglePageViewer(this.getPDFOptions());
      }
      this.pdfLinkService.setViewer(this.pdfViewer);
  
      this.pdfViewer._currentPageNumber = this._page;
    }
  
    private getValidPageNumber(page: number): number {
      if (page < 1) {
        return 1;
      }
  
      if (page > this._pdf.numPages) {
        return this._pdf.numPages;
      }
  
      return page;
    }
  
    private getDocumentParams() {
      const srcType = typeof this.src;
  
      if (!this._cMapsUrl) {
        return this.src;
      }
  
      const params: any = {
        cMapUrl: this._cMapsUrl,
        cMapPacked: true,
        enableXfa: true
      };
  
      if (srcType === 'string') {
        params.url = this.src;
      } else if (srcType === 'object') {
        if ((this.src as any).byteLength !== undefined) {
          params.data = this.src;
        } else {
          Object.assign(params, this.src);
        }
      }
  
      return params;
    }
  
    private loadPDF() {
      if (!this.src) {
        return;
      }
  
      if (this.lastLoaded === this.src) {
        this.update();
        return;
      }
  
      this.clear();
  
      this.setupViewer();
  
      this.loadingTask = PDFJS.getDocument(this.getDocumentParams());
  
      this.loadingTask.onProgress = (progressData: PDFProgressData) => {
        this.onProgress.emit(progressData);
      };
  
      const src = this.src;
  
      from(this.loadingTask.promise as Promise<PDFDocumentProxy>)
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
        .subscribe({
          next: (pdf) => {
            this._pdf = pdf;
            this.lastLoaded = src;
  
            this.afterLoadComplete.emit(pdf);
            this.resetPdfDocument();
  
            this.update();
          },
          error: (error) => {
            this.lastLoaded = null;
            this.onError.emit(error);
          }
        });
    }
  
    private update() {
      this.page = this._page;
  
      this.render();
    }
  
    private render() {
      this._page = this.getValidPageNumber(this._page);
  
      if (
        this._rotation !== 0 ||
        this.pdfViewer.pagesRotation !== this._rotation
      ) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.pdfViewer.pagesRotation = this._rotation;
        });
      }
  
      if (this._stickToPage) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.pdfViewer.currentPageNumber = this._page;
        });
      }
  
      this.updateSize();
    }
  
    private getScale(viewportWidth: number, viewportHeight: number) {
      const borderSize = this._showBorders ? 2 * PdfViewerComponent.BORDER_WIDTH : 0;
      const pdfContainerWidth = this.pdfViewerContainer.nativeElement.clientWidth - borderSize;
      const pdfContainerHeight = this.pdfViewerContainer.nativeElement.clientHeight - borderSize;
  
      if (
        pdfContainerHeight === 0 ||
        viewportHeight === 0 ||
        pdfContainerWidth === 0 ||
        viewportWidth === 0
      ) {
        return 1;
      }
  
      let ratio = 1;
      switch (this._zoomScale) {
        case 'page-fit':
          ratio = Math.min(
            pdfContainerHeight / viewportHeight,
            pdfContainerWidth / viewportWidth
          );
          break;
        case 'page-height':
          ratio = pdfContainerHeight / viewportHeight;
          break;
        case 'page-width':
        default:
          ratio = pdfContainerWidth / viewportWidth;
          break;
      }
  
      return (this._zoom * ratio) / PdfViewerComponent.CSS_UNITS;
    }
  
    private resetPdfDocument() {
      this.pdfLinkService.setDocument(this._pdf, null);
      this.pdfFindController.setDocument(this._pdf);
      this.pdfViewer.setDocument(this._pdf);
    }
  
    private initialize(): void {
      if (isSSR() || !this.isVisible) {
        return;
      }
  
      this.isInitialized = true;
      this.initEventBus();
      this.setupViewer();
    }
  
    private setupResizeListener(): void {
      if (isSSR()) {
        return;
      }
  
      this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        fromEvent(window, 'resize')
          .pipe(
            debounceTime(100),
            filter(() => this._canAutoResize && !!this._pdf),
            takeUntil(this.destroy$)
          )
          .subscribe(() => {
            this.updateSize();
          });
      });
    }
  }
```

file 3 : pdf-viewer.component.scss

```
.ng2-pdf-viewer-container {
    overflow-x: auto;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  
  :host {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }
```

[please find attached file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDrZr.png)

I tried multiple solution but not getting expected answer,
Expected Result : I want only one scroll bar for all the pdf files

Comment: please provide sample code, it will be easy to understand get fixed asap..

Comment: @Jason0011 added supporting files